# Exchange 2007 - How to use export-mailbox function?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, powershell

I am trying to use the Export-Mailbox cmdlet to export a mailbox to PST file but i get an error that i'm running on a 64bit machine and must use a 32 bit etc etc..

I have a Windows 7 Pro 32bit PC joined to the domain with the exchange server, and outlook 32bit installed. When i try to install Exchange 2007 32bit management console only, i'm told that i can't install the managemnet tools on a Windows 7 PC.

Can someone please advise if this is correct setup to be able to run the export-mailbox function to dump the mailboxes into PST files.

Thank you

Comment: Generally, you'll get better performance exporting the mailboxes locally on the server and you won't have to deal with the client issues.  Just food for thought.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

[Importing and Exporting Mailbox data to and from PST files Exchange 2007](http://ali.vg/2011/02/importing-and-exporting-mailbox-data-to-and-from-pst-files-exchange-2007/)

Comment: I'd upvote if you could paraphrase the link.